# SQL Aggregation with rolling window

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, rdbms

hope someone could enlighten me.
I have a weekly based data with column - last day of that week, also type and duration. 
And I want to aggregate duration for each type in separate column for each week (get it to week #1, week #2, etc.) for each id.

So, this is input:

```
+-----+---------------+------+----------+
| id  | week end date | type | duration |
+-----+---------------+------+----------+
| 101 | 14.07.2017    | A    | 5        |
| 101 | 14.07.2017    | A    | 1        |
| 101 | 14.07.2017    | B    | 4        |
| 101 | 14.07.2017    | C    | 2        |
| 101 | 21.07.2017    | A    | 4        |
| …   | …             | …    | …        |
| 102 | 14.07.2017    | A    | 2        |
| 102 | 14.07.2017    | B    | 4        |
+-----+---------------+------+----------+
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
+---------+----------+-------+-------+---+
|     id  | Week num | A_sum | B_sum | … |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+---+
|     101 |        1 |     6 |     4 |   |
|     101 |        2 |     5 |     8 |   |
|     101 |        3 |     5 |     5 |   |
|     …   |          |       |       |   |
|     102 |        1 |     5 |     2 |   |
|     102 |        2 |     8 |     2 |   |
+---------+----------+-------+-------+---+
```

For this case number of types is small, so we can manually define new columns as 
`SUM(CASE WHEN type='A' THEN duration ELSE 0 END) "A"`

In general seems feasible, but I cant assemble it all together..

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
select
    id,
    dense_rank() over(order by week_end_date) week_num
    sum(case when type = 'A' then duration end) a,
    sum(case when type = 'B' then duration end) b,
    sum(case when type = 'C' then duration end) c
from mytable
group by id, week_end_date
```

The query dynamically generates week numbers based on the dates available in the table (the first date gets week 1, and so on). Then, we aggregate by id and week, and do conditional sums to compute the totals.

Comment: Only one issue that in such case we will get continious week numbers through all table, not limited per each ID.

Comment: @Oleksii: if you want a per-id week number, then `dense_rank() over(partition by id order by week_end_date) week_num`